# Add object to observable collection based on created class

Tags: c#

I've created a class named Materials:

```
public class Materials : ObservableObject
{
    private List<String> _mat1List;
    public List<String> Mat1List
    {
        get { return _mat1List; }
        set { _mat1List = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private List<String> _mat2List;
    public List<String> Mat2List
    {
        get { return _mat2List; }
        set { _mat2List = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private List<String> _mat3List;
    public List<String> Mat3List
    {
        get { return _mat3List; }
        set { _mat3List = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }

    private List<String> _mat4List;
    public List<String> Mat4List
    {
        get { return _mat4List; }
        set { _mat4List = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}
```

Then I create 4 temporary lists to store info about them:

```
MaterialCollection = new ObservableCollection<Materials>();
ObservableCollection<String> tempMat1List = new ObservableCollection<String>();
ObservableCollection<String> tempMat2List = new ObservableCollection<String>();
ObservableCollection<String> tempMat3List = new ObservableCollection<String>();
ObservableCollection<String> tempMat4List = new ObservableCollection<String>();
```

After gathering all info about them, I cannot add them to my MaterialCollection:

```
MaterialCollection.Add( tempMat1List, tempMat2List, tempMat3List, tempMat4List );
```

Any tips please?

Comment: can you provide error messages etc.?

Comment: My idea is to make a collection, in which each element is composed by 4 lists

Comment: Compiler Error CS1501: No overload for method 'Add' takes 4 arguments

Comment: you need to use `AddRange` instead of  `Add` or add each item separatly

Comment: Thanks for the help. But in that case, when I write "MaterialCollection[0].Mat1List" and "MaterialCollection[0].Mat2List" and so on, will I have acess to each list separately? I want to each instance of MaterialCollection to be a group of 4 lists. Thanks

Comment: Also, you cannot use AddRange with ObservableCollection

Comment: This question may lead to a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I think you may should review your class model (domain model) I guess there is a missconception of list in list...

Comment: the only type you can add to MaterialCollection is `Materials`. prefill it with your inner lists and then add it.

Comment: Sorry my mistakes, but how should I create a class that requires 4 lists as parameters? I'm kind lost now..

Comment: A tuple, a class with 4 fields, .. there are many options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement a constructor for `Materials` which takes four lists and feed your `_mat1List`, `_mat2List` and so on.

```
Materials(List<string> materialList1, List<string> materialList2, List<string> materialList3, List<string> materialList4)
{
this._mat1List = materialList1;
this._mat2List = materialList2;
//...
}
```

And then you could do

```
MaterialCollection.Add(new Materials(tempMat1List, tempMat2List, tempMat3List, tempMat4List));
```

Please notice that as said in the comments, `.Add` method expects one parameter of the type of the collection you are adding it to.